# Is there any algorithm better than O(N) to find the first bit set in a bitarray that consists mostly of continous blocks?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

Suppose that we have a bitarray and we know that array has very low complexity: it consists mostly of continuous chunks of "1"s or "0"s. That is, if we read two consecutive bits, the chance of them being identical is much higher than 50%. For example:

```
00001111100011100000111111100000
```

This is a typical array on this format, since it consists mostly of continous chunks of the same bit. So is this one:

```
00000000000000000000011111111000
```

But this is not:

```
10100110001010011100110001000111
```

That concept could be formalized in more precise ways, such as *"iterating through the array we see at most log(N) bit changes"*, or *"the chance of 2 consecutive bits being identical is >95%"*, but I'm not sure this matters.

My question is: what is a fast algorithm to find the index of the first bit set on the bit array (that is, `1`)?

Comment: Are you looking for a "probably" solution or a definite one? For a definite one, you will need to see all bits prior to the first set one, no going around that.

Comment: I don't think you can do better than the O(N) approach of "scan each bit one-by-one until you find the 1". Even if there's a 99.99999% chance of two adjacent bits being identical, you can't skip ahead, because of the 0.000001% chance you'll skip the bit you need.

Comment: I'm happy with a probabilistic solution! As in, very low chances of missing the right answer. The fact is this algorithm is running several times on very similar arrays, so the error could be corrected on the next computations. Having wrong results for a few consecutive frames is OK. Anyway, if this can be shown to be doable in less than O(1) without errors that's better, of course.

Comment: I guess you can do a little better if you want a probabilistic solution. If you use the "check only every Xth bit" strategy, then I suspect there's a nice mathematical relationship between consecutive bit identicality chance, and likelihood of missing the first changeover. In that case, the question becomes "what _is_ that relationship?" so you can find the correct value of X to get your desired failure rate.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is Most Significant Bit. With that term, you can find a lot of different ways to retrieve it, if you haven't already been there!

Comment: Do you want to query only once, or would O(n log n) preprocessing be acceptable, for example?

Comment: I'm not sure it would be possible to preprocess this. I have a really huge array of bits (~ 1gb) and the search is actually done in arbitrary orders (for example, I could read the bit at index 3, then 7, then 19, then 90, then 1988093 - and that would be the first 5 bits of the array). The condition described on the thread still holds for any order I can chose, i.e., bits 3 and 7 will probably be the same.

Comment: I am curious as to the application of this problem. Maybe more context would help us find something better.

Comment: This is just for ray tracing in a regular grid. I'm trying to figure out if I can make the ray step less than O(N) times in exchange for some accuracy.

Comment: By the way, I think you want the word "contiguous" rather than "continuous."

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your system, the Count Leading Zeros operation `clz` could make this go quite a bit faster.  This is common in ARM architectures.  With this operation, you can count many unset bits at once.  That with some shifting (basically free in ARM) could speed things up quite a bit.  Count 0s, not bits, shift away known bits, repeat.

Still linear-esque, but a much faster linear for sure - especially if the data has a lot of runs in it as you suggest.

Comment: It's common in x86. In fact it's commonly used by OSes to manage memory allocations. I didn't realize it's implemented in ARM as well.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined your input model unambiguously but let's say that it follows a Markov chain. That means that the first bit is whatever it is, and then when you move from one bit to the next, the probability of bits switching values is p and the probability of remaining the same is (1-p). If you know p, and p is small, you can make some progress on this problem. First check the first bit. If it is 1, then you are done. Otherwise you are looking for the first transition from 0 to 1. Note that if you consider k consecutive bits at a time, then the probability of getting exactly one transition in these k bits is k*p*(1-p)^(k-1). On the other hand, the probability of getting 2 or more transitions is essentially the same as getting exactly 2 transitions if p is small relative to k, and this probability is k*(k-1)*p^2*(1-p)^(k-2)/2. You want the first quantity to be not too small and the second quantity to be much smaller. This will happen for example if you choose k = round(1/sqrt(p)). Then if p is small the probability you get one transition over k consecutive bits is essentially sqrt(p), while the probability you get two transitions is essentially p/2, which is much smaller. So just check every kth bit until you see a 1, and then binary search between the previous and current positions to find the first occurrence of a 1. With high probability this will be the first occurrence of a 1. The expected running time is O(sqrt(p)*n + log(k)) assuming the Markov chain model, and the probability of error is O(sqrt(p)). So if p is small and you know p, this is a good compromise (of course, if you accept the model).

Comment: That's a very interesting answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you could treat the bit array as a byte (or word) array. Read bytes until you get a byte that isn't 0. Then use one of the Bit Hacks similar to [this one](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup) to determine which of the bits in that byte is set.

The algorithm goes something like this:

```
bitPosition = 0
byteIndex = 0
while (array[byteIndex] == 0)
{
    bitPosition += 8;
    ++byteIndex;
}
bitPosition += GetFirstSetBit(array[byteIndex]);
```

That's O(n/8), which is still technically O(n), but it's going to be a lot faster than checking every bit.

Come to think of it, you could do that with words, dwords, or quadwords and realize even more savings, depending on your hardware.

If you then want to find the 0 bit that follows the first 1 bit, then the next 1 bit, etc., this algorithm still works. For example if you're reading by bytes and you find that the first set bit is bit 4, you set the top three bits (which were previously 0), invert the value, and search for the first set bit. If no bit is set, then you go back into the reading bytes loop, but invert each value as you read it.

You could continue in that manner indefinitely. It's still O(n), but the constant is significantly smaller than if you were checking each bit individually.

Comment: This is `clz`, except `clz` gives you the offset to the 1 byte in 1 step. :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I understand. But the OP tagged his question as language-agnostic. So I provided an answer that doesn't assume any particular architecture.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem at hand is stepping along a ray traveling though 3D array until you hit a change in pixel value. There are two very different approaches that I'm aware of that accelerate such searches. Both are useful only if you have to perform the above operation for numerous rays, whether rays coming from the same point in various directions or rays coming from a variety of starting point. I've go some experience of doing that for very large 2D grids (of floats rather than bools), but generalization to 3D is straightforward.

The 1st approach is to start by building a [mipmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) of your grid. That is, for each 2x2 set of pixels in 2D (or 2x2x2 set of pixels in 3D) store the number of non-zero values in the "2nd level" grid. Then for each 2x2 (or 2x2x2) set in the 2nd level grid add up those number into the "3rd level" grid. Continue until you end up with a handful of pixels in the "highest level" grid. Notice that on the Nth level grid pixels are 2^N times taller and wider (and deeper in 3D case) than the original ones.

Suppose now you are searching for the closest pixel of value 1 starting from the given point in the given direction. After you step to the border of you current 2nd level grid you can check the value of the next 2nd level pixels in the direction of you ray. If your data is really sparse chances are that that pixels would indicate that all its entries are either 0s or 1s. Therefore you can skip over the entire pixel. And now you are on the border of the 3rd level grid, the one that holds 4x4x4 pixels. If your data is really Really sparse you again will have the same value for all pixels and can step over into the 4th level grid, the one with 8x8x8 pixels. If your data is really Really REALLY sparse you can step over again into 16x16x16 realm... Finally you got to an Nth level grid that tells you that there are pixels of different values there. Now you can start decreasing the level of grid you are looking into until you find the pixel of different value. If the changes in your data are extremely sparse the above search should take O(log N).

There are variety of mipmaps for anisotropic data, with different rates of resolution change in different direction. The best choice would depend on the details of the problem at hand.

Now, the 2nd approach is building a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) for 2D data or [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) for 3D data. The basic idea, just as with mipmaps, is to search sparse data in O(log N) time. However, there are several fundamental differences.

First, quadtree (and octrees) are organized as trees rather than arrays. Second, they encode the transitions between pixel values rather than pixel values. Third, they can have very variable depth in different regions of your data, depending on the level of density of data transitions in those regions.

The latter feature, the ability to vary depth depending on data density, leads to much better performance than mipmaps when the density of transitions is sufficiently variable. It's very possible for unfortunate input data eliminate mipmap advantage, but such misfortunes are more rare with quadtrees.

For industrial quality application it may be worthwhile to try both approaches and see which one would lead to better performance. For example, it may happen that quadrees would perform better on a CPU and mipmaps better on a GPU, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in less than *O(N)* where *N* is the number of array elements, but you don't have to scan each bit:

```
public class FirstBitSet
{
    private static final int[] lookup =
    {
        0, 1, 2, 27, 3, 24, 28, 7, 4, 17, 25, 31, 29, 12, 14, 14,
        5, 8, 18, 29, 26, 23, 32, 16, 30, 11, 13, 7, 28, 22, 15, 10,
        6, 21, 9, 20, 19,
    };

    public static int   firstBitSet(int i)
    {
        int j = i & -i;
        int k = j % 37;
        k = Math.abs(k);
        int b = lookup[k];
        return b;
    }
}
```

E&OE. There could be some errors in the table, but you get the idea.

Note that this doesn't work for zero input values, so you have to filter them out.

Comment: Is that lookup table encoding a de Bruijn sequence?  I've seen that done using a `*`, but never a `%`.  I certainly don't "get the idea" yet, some more explanation would be good!

Answer (score 1):

Several answers here.

First, strictly speaking, you cannot do better than O(N), because you've got to scan each bit one way or another. Given the problem statement, most you can hope for is reduce the constant coefficient in O(N).

Second, many processors have [hardware support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) that would enable you to scan a word at a time rather than a bit at a time.

Thirdly, and most importantly, I suspect you can improve performance of your application by changing the way you represent your data. [Run-length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) is very efficient for encoding this kind of data for much much much faster processing.

Fourth, Run-length encoding combines rather nicely with [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). On the dawn of my career I was dealing with [Modified Huffman codes](http://web.archive.org/web/20020628195336/http://www.netnam.vn/unescocourse/computervision/104.htm) for emulating fax machine. Fax data looks roughly like yours: stretches of 1s followed by stretches of 0s; this data is typically transmitted as Huffman-coded run lengths of continuously identical bits. There are some additional clever optimizations in Modified Huffman codes; for example, only run lengths are encoded, w/out quoting the bit corresponding to the run, under the assumption that the bit flips between the runs, etc.

I don't know the exact nature of your algorithm, but if it's anything like image processing or signal processing, with the bits corresponding to the pixel/signal not changing over a stretch of time, run-length encoding would take you very far, whether or not you choose to combine it with additional compression via Huffman or other codes.

Comment: But that data represents a 3d array, and a ray travels through it in arbitrary directions, so I think that kind of compression can't help very much, correct? After all, we would lose the connection between the array indexes and the values stored.

Comment: @Viclib, depending what are you going to do with the data further, there is a variety of solutions to compress 2D and 3D pixel data. Serendipitously I'm currently working on measuring length of rays in 2D arrays, and certain data structures help. Let me add another answer rather than a comment because these things require more chars than a comment would allow.